# Image deforms when I change the height of a parent element

Tags: html, css

For some reason, my `img` element deforms along with its parent element (`#purp`) when I try to change the parent's height from 800 to 650 pixels. How can I prevent this from happening?
Here's the code and the screenshots:

```
#purp{
    height:800px;
    background: linear-gradient(114deg,rgba(115, 0, 255, 0.781) 0%,  rgba(21,57,198,0.7811) 100%);
    margin-top:150px;
    display:flex;
    clip-path: polygon(50% 18%, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
}

#purp img{
    transform: scale(.55);
    margin-left:-50px;
}
```

Before:
[Parent's height of 800px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3a1N.png)

After:
[Parents height of 650px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isq4O.png)

Comment: well the image ratio does no further fit. So you need to set an `object-fit` value like `contain, cover or scale-down`.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem :)

Comment: add  `align-items: center;` for `#purp`

Comment: This is because the image is constrained to the parents height an width, therefor it is `stretching` outside of the original images aspect ratio to *'fit'* the parents height and width.